# Understanding the cohomology class associated to some closed submanifold

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

> Let $Z$ be a closed submanifold in some ambient manifold, and $T$ be a tubular neighborhood of $Z$. Assume $dimZ=n$ and $dimT=n+r$. So we have a map $\pi:T\to Z$ with fibers of dimension $r$. Let $[Z]\in H^{r}(T,\mathbb Z)$ be the cohomology class associated to $Z$. Then it claims
>   $$\pi_*[Z]=1$$

I want to know how to prove this?

---

I can only understand the definitions. The $[Z]$ is defined by the image of $1\in H^0(Z)$ in the composition
$$H^0(Z)\xrightarrow[\text{ isomorphism}]{\text{Thom}} H^r(T,T-Z) \to H^r(T)$$
and the $\pi_*$ in $\pi_*[Z]$ should be understood as the Poincare duality of the map
$$H_n(T)\to H_n(Z)$$
which is
$$H^r(T)\to H^0(Z)$$
But I don't know how to think about $\pi_*[Z]$ then.

Comment: Have you considered concatenating the first line and the third line into one long composite map from $H^0(Z)$ to itself? If the first line sends $1\mapsto [Z]$ and the third line sends $[X]\to\pi_*[X]$, is it clear what to do here?

Comment: @KReiser But why the composition $1\mapsto \pi_*[Z]=1$? In fact I don't know how to think about $[Z]$.

Comment: I'm slightly confused by what you meant about the Poincare duality of the map, since $T$ is not compact - but you can probably just replace this with compactly supported cohomology, or Lefschetz duality. Anyway, the answer to your question boils down to knowing that the Thom class of your normal bundle gives you the poincare dual of your submanifold.

Comment: @loch Yes, I should replace it by compactly supported cohomology. Could you give a reference about the fact you mentioned about Thom class?

Comment: @Akatsuki A proof - at least with real coefficients - that Thom class of normal bundle is the poincare dual of the submanifold can be found in Bott and Tu's "differential forms in algebraic topology"